# perl parsing files for multiple strings

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have been learning perl for the past two weeks. I have been writing some perl scripts for my school project. I need to parse a text file for multiple strings. I searched perl forums and got some information.The below function parses a text file for one string   and returns a result. However I need the script to search the file for multiple strings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


sub find_string {
    my ($file, $string) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        return 1 if /\Q$string/;
    }
    die "Unable to find string: $string";
}

find_string('filename', 'string');
```

Now for instance if the file contains multiple strings with regular expressions as listed below

```
"testing"
http://www.yahoo.com =1
http://www.google.com=2
```

I want the function to search for multiple strings like

```
find_string('filename', 'string1','string2','string3');
```

Please can somebody explain me how i need to do that.It would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Going through this very quickly here:

You right now pass the name of a file, and one string. What if you pass multiple strings:

```
 if ( find_string ( $file, @strings ) ) {
    print "Found a string!\n";
}
else {
    print "No string found\n";
}


..

sub find_string {
    my $file    = shift;
    my @strings = @_;
    #
    # Let's make the strings into a regular expression
    #
    my $reg_exp = join "|" ,@strings;   # Regex is $string1|$string2|$string3...

    open my $fh, "<", $file or die qq(Can't open file...);
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
       chomp $line;
       if ( $line =~ $reg_exp ) {
           return 1;     # Found the string
       }
    }
    return 0;            # String not found
}
```

I am about to go into a meeting, so I haven't really even tested this, but the idea is there. A few things:

- You want to handle characters in your strings that could be regular expression characters. You can use either the `quotemeta` command, or use `\Q` and `\E` before and after each string.
- Think about using `use autodie` to handle files that can't be open. Then, you don't have to check your open statement (like I did above).
- There are limitations. This would be awful if you were searching for 1,000 different strings, but should be okay with a few.
- Note how I use a scalar file handle (`$fh`). Instead of opening your file via the subroutine, I would pass in a scalar file handle. This would allow you to take care of an invalid file issue in your main program. That's the big advantage of scalar file handles: They can be easily passed to subroutines and stored in class objects.

---

## Tested Program

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    INPUT_FILE =>       'test.txt',
};


open my $fh, "<", INPUT_FILE;

my @strings = qw(foo fo+*o bar fubar);

if ( find_string ( $fh, @strings ) ) {
    print "Found a string!\n";
}
else {
    print "No string found\n";
}

sub find_string {
    my $fh    = shift;          # The file handle
    my @strings = @_;           # A list of strings to look for

    #
    # We need to go through each string to make sure there's
    # no special re characters
    for my $string ( @strings ) {
        $string = quotemeta $string;
    }

    #
    # Let's join the stings into one big regular expression
    #
    my $reg_exp = join '|', @strings;   # Regex is $string1|$string2|$string3...
    $reg_exp = qr($reg_exp);            # This is now a regular expression

    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ $reg_exp ) {
            return 1;     # Found the string
        }
    }
    return 0;            # String not found
}
```

- `autodie` handles issues when I can't open a file. No need to check for it.
- Notice I have three parameters in my `open`. This is the preferred way.
- My file handle is `$fh` which allows me to pass it to my `find_string` subroutine. Open the file in the main program, and I can handle read errors there.
- I loop through my `@strings` and use the `quotemeta` command to automatically escape special regular expression characters.
- Note that when I change `$string` in my loop, it actually modifies the `@strings` array.
- I use `qr` to create a regular expression.
- My regular expression is `/foo|fo\+\*o|bar|fubar/`.
- There are a few *bugs* For example, the string `fooburberry` will match with `foo`. Do you want that, or do you want your *strings* to be whole words?

Comment: thanks for the response. Where do i need to specify the strings that i need to search..I want to search string1,string2,string3.How do i make the function call. Pardon my ignorance. I have taken a programming course for the first time.

Comment: You pass the strings to the function call like you originally did. Notice that `find_string` does `my @strings = @_;`. This takes everything else off of the list. You originally assumed that the `@_` array will have two elements. I am assuming somewhere between two and infinity.

Comment: See the tested program in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to see `use strict` and `use warnings` in your script. Here is one basic way to do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


sub find_string {

    my ($file, $string1, $string2, $string3) = @_;

    my $found1 = 0;
    my $found2 = 0;
    my $found3 = 0;

    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        if ( /$string1/ ) {
            $found1 = 1;
        }
        if ( /$string2/ ) {
            $found2 = 1;
        }
        if ( /$string3/ ) {
            $found3 = 1;
        }
    }

    if ( $found1 == 1 and $found2 == 1 and $found3 == 1 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

my $result = find_string('filename', 'string1'. 'string2', 'string3');

if ( $result == 1 ) {
    print "Found all three strings\n";
} else {
    print "Didn't find all three\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to find 5-10 strings.In that case i need to create $found 1 ...$found n .So is there any other way to find it.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you just put that in your question to begin with. But yeah there are lots of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the file content in an array first, then grep the input in the array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub find_multi_string {
    my ($file, @strings) = @_; 
    my $fh;
    open ($fh, "<$file");
    #store the whole file in an array
    my @array = <$fh>;

    for my $string (@strings) {
        if (grep /$string/, @array) {
            next;
        } else {
            die "Cannot find $string in $file";
        }   
    }   

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: .How do i make the function call for this .find_multi_string('filename', 'string1','string2','string3'); Will this work??